# i want to implement SCIM with the help of an idP

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma, okta-api, scim2

i'm working in nestjs/prima/postegre project and i can't find any similair code source ressource, how i can update my prisma schema to fit SCIM models or is there any similar project for inspiration?

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["filterJson"]
  // previewFeatures = []
}

generator dbml {
  provider = "prisma-dbml-generator"
}

model User {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  firstname String?
  lastname  String?
  posts     Post[]
  role      Role
}

model Post {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  published Boolean
  title     String
  content   String?
  author    User?    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  String?
}

enum Role {
  ADMIN
  USER
}
```